# Windows 10 does not display speed graph when moving files in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Windows 10 sometimes does not display speed graph when moving files in Windows Explorer, e.g.:

[image]

Whereas typically it displays a speed graph:

[image]

What could explain it?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: After reinstalled W10HE (10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363) have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I found this out by having external monitor, the screen scaling 150% does not show it, scale 100% shows it. Microsoft at its finest :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).